# Call native contact insertion activity with a custom Android Account

Tags: android, android-activity, contacts, account

I have created my own account (with a custom account type as well) to use in combination with my application but when I want to insert or edit a contact through the Address Book application on this account, it does not trigger the native activity but a custom one with just name fields...

Do you know how I can trigger the full native one instead?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You need to add your own Activity. 
One way is to add a profile action and handle it.
See here: [open an activity to edit contact in sync adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344841/open-an-activity-to-edit-contact-in-sync-adapter).

Se also: [honeycomb sync adapter features for editing contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343372/honeycomb-sync-adapter-features-for-editing-contacts) although there is no answer you can find useful links I found when I was dealing with it

In the example that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344841/open-an-activity-to-edit-contact-in-sync-adapter) there is only the Edit intent but it is enough to replace the action with ACTION_INSERT for the other case

Comment: I have added two actions one for editing the contact and the second one to send a voip message