# How can I have my activity display in android contact menu, like i.e. facebook app?

Tags: android

I would like to launch my android application from a contact menu which is displayed after clicking on a contact shortcut on android desktop, like on attached graphic.

I couldn't find any materials on this in docs, but I think it should be possible, as i.e. facebook application puts it's icon in this menu. I tried to find something in it's AndroidManifest.xml file but with no effect (I'm not familiar with android development so I don't even know what to look for - Activity, intent, intent-filter, provider?

I would appreciate link to docs or at least hint on terminology to google for.

//edit

It seems that my question is duplicate of : [How to integrate your app in QUICK CONTACT on the native contact app on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858819/how-to-integrate-your-app-in-quick-contact-on-the-native-contact-app-on-android) which has some helpful resources.

[image: screenshot showing the menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called quick actions in android by the way..

[Here is a nice tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped me find out that my question is in fact a duplicate. Edited original question to include link.